# Changing Tab on Image Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I try for some time now to set the active Tab of this theme when the user clicks an image (above the tabs).

http://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/Nova/

[image: http://imageupload.org/en/file/192843/tabclickexample.png.html]

I found the normal tab change code in the scripts.php, but I have no idea of how to change it to make it work with clicking any image that are above the tabs.

```
            $service_li.find('a').click(function(){
                var $a = jQuery(this),
                    next_tab = $a.parent('li').prevAll().length,
                    next_tab_height = $service_tabs.find('>div').eq(next_tab).outerHeight();

                if ( next_tab != active_tab ) {
                    $service_tabs.css({height:next_tab_height});
                    $service_div.filter(':visible')
                        .animate( {opacity: 'hide'},500, function(){
                            jQuery(this).parent().find('>div').eq(next_tab).animate( {opacity: 'show'},500 );
                        } )
                        ;
                    $service_li.removeClass(active_tabstate).filter(':eq('+next_tab+')').addClass(active_tabstate);
                    active_tab = next_tab;
                }

                return false;
            }).hover(function(){
                if ( !jQuery(this).parent('li').hasClass(active_tabstate) && !is_ie ) jQuery(this).fadeTo('slow',.7);
            }, function(){
                if (!is_ie) jQuery(this).fadeTo('slow',1);
            });
        }
```

Maybe someone can help out ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what or better yet, why you've conjured that thing over there, but i would use [jQuery Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/), so you can easily access the tab object by entering the `id` in the URL (firefox only) or by using something like.. `.tabs( "select" , index )`  , you can find more documentation in the URL above.

Comment: sry, but that's not what I am looking for. Implementing jquery tabs would mess up my whole theme and would require additional styling etc. The tabs are fine just as they are. I just need to link to them.